# Table cell not showing items of Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all, I've looked around to find a solution to my problem, here and on other websites. If I've missed something please show me the link, i didn't intend on bugging you with my problem if there is a solution somewhere else.

My idea was to create an app (just for myself as a practise since I'm fairly new to swift) that would get the NBA schedule from a website, extract the games and results and show them in a table. For that I made a textField where the user could enter from which game day he wanted the results. The Integer he enters changes the url and the url is propperly spilt up and the data I want to display is saved in an array as a string.

Thats were my problem occurs. The items are appended to the array and the array.count displays the right number depending on the day the user entered. The only problem is that the data from the array is not display in the table cell. I've rewrote the code and made sure I didn't mess up the table, but as soon as I add the second part of the app (the information that got from the URL) to the app, the cells don't display anything.

It's kind of weird because both parts are working fine on their own, but as soon as I combine them my problem occurs. Do you know where I might have messed up?

Does anyone have an idea what my mistake may be? I'm not looking for code solutions, just for someone who might tell me where the flaw in my logic is. Maybe i missed something, but i don't get why my cells are not displaying the elements of the array, even though the array is set up properly.

Thanks in advance to anyone answering and have a nice day!
Greetings!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var gamesArray = [String]()

    var gameDay:Int = 0

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var gamesTable: UITableView!

    @IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    gameDay = Int(textField.text!)!
    // webCodeArrayForGames is where i temporarily put the strings I want to add

    for var counter = 1; counter<webCodeArrayForGames.count; counter++{
        self.gamesArray.append(webCodeArrayForGames[counter])               

        }

    override func viewDidLoad()
   {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    gamesTable.delegate = self
    gamesTable.dataSource = self
   }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection     section: Int) -> Int {
        return gamesArray.count
     }

    func TableView(tableView: UITableView, cellforRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = gamesArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.gamesTable.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: After you finish retrieving the data, are you calling `reloadData` on the table view? If you're retrieving data asynchronously, you'll have to trigger a reload of the table in order to see the new data. If that's not it, there's no way we can diagnose this on the basis of the information provided. You need to include [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note, that does not mean we want to see all of your code. You should create the simplest possible example (removing _everything_ not directly related to the problem) that manifests the behavior you describe.

Comment: Second Rob's comment about needing to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in order to tell the table that it needs to update it's content. Try putting a breakpoint at `numberOfIemsInSection` and see if it returns the result that you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I still wasn't able to get rid of my problem. I just added the relevant code, maybe this lets you find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this one:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAPIOverview/TableViewAPIOverview.html

On the short, you have to provide UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

From the code, I suspect that you didn't provide the dataSource for your table:
"The data source adopts the UITableViewDataSource protocol. UITableViewDataSource has two required methods. The tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method tells the table view how many rows to display in each section, and the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method provides the cell to display for each row in the table. "

You could do this way:

1. Subclass your viewController from UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { ....
   ```
2. in viewDidLoad() assign the tableview's delegate and dataSource:

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gamesTable.delegate = self
        gamesTable.dataSource = self ....
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you were right I did in fact forget to subclass my viewController from UITableViewDataSource. I did that now and added the part in viewDidLoad, but unfortunately, it's still not displaying the content in the cell

Comment: Hi, sorry to hear that. Do you correctly use this one?            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell"). I mean, do you have "cell" for your reuse identifier in storyboard?

Comment: yeah I have. I'm just gonna continue studying and working in my swift course, maybe I'll find out what was wrong later on when I learn new things. Thank you for trying to help me though, I appreciate it

Comment: Ok, Ari. Good luck with your course! Or maybe you can start over with your project.